# Jest SuperTest: Giving error in Open Handler when using setTimeout in the class-under-test

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest, supertest

i am writing a E2E in Jest/Supertest in Nest JS (node) environment.

I have searched extensively about this pretty common error:
`Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting:`

Implemented every solutions suggested.

However getting this in a `setTimeout` method intermittently as follows:

```
Test Suites: 2 passed, 2 total
Tests:       6 passed, 6 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        135.464 s
Ran all test suites.

Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting:

  ●  Timeout

      49 |   },
      50 |   delay(millisecond: number) {
    > 51 |     return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, millisecond));
         |                                     ^
      52 |   },
      53 | };
      54 |
```

Here is my setTimeout code:

```
  // The API
  async create<T>(key: string, item: T): Promise<T> {
    await this.delay(5000);
    return this.createWithoutDelay(key, item);
  }

  // The delay method code
  delay(millisecond: number) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, millisecond));
  },
```

My tests are very simple:

```
    beforeAll(async () => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
           ......
    app = moduleUnderTest.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
    // Reference the server instance
    server = app.getHttpServer();
  });

  it('Test: Create Object', async () => {
    const response = await request(server).post('/object')
      .send({
        name: 'new-object',
      });

    expect(response.status).toEqual(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    expect(response.body).toBeDefined();
    expect(Array.isArray(response.body)).toBeFalsy();
    const jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response.text);
    expect(jsonResponse.name).toEqual('new-object');
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await app.close();
    await server.close();
  });
```

The following are my Jest config:

```
module.exports = {
  moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "json", "ts"],
  verbose: true,
  preset: "ts-jest",
  rootDir: ".",

  testTimeout: 15000,
  fakeTimers: {
    timerLimit: 15000,
  },

  testEnvironment: "node",
  testRegex: ".e2e-spec.ts$",

  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
  },

  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^axios$': require.resolve('axios'),
  },
};
```

In the Jest cmd, I am passing: `--runInBand --forceExit --detectOpenHandles`

Any clue shall be helpful.